# Objective C Framework to Browse and Manage Documents or Files

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Just so I do not happen to reinvent the wheel, and at least check out some examples, is there a well known framework in objective C which will allow me to view and manage documents inside folder(s):

- browse folder documents/files
- display documents as thumbnails or as a list
- allow me to manage files: delete, move, etc.

I am not looking for Photo Viewer or PDF Viewer really, just a file manager or simply viewer. Thanks.

Comment: `NSFileManager` and `UITableView`.

Comment: Right, but how about a more advanced option, such as open source framework that takes you further. For example, PTShowcaseViewController or vfr/Viewer both available at Github?

Comment: Are you answering your own question? The suggestion from @rmaddy should suffice. Alternatively if you're looking for a full solution there are a number of apps on the App Store that do what you're describing.

Comment: @aqua: perhaps, but these are what I found after I posted a question. they do not seem to be that widely used but it may be worth looking at them. I still hope to hear more.